# Convert Swift Array<Result<X,Error>> in to Result<Array<X>, Error>

Tags: swift, generics

I have an array of Swift `Result`, like this:

```
let tuple: [Result<Term, TermError>] = /* code here */
```

I want to turn this inside out, pulling the results out to give a single result, with the array pushed inside it.

```
let tuple2: Result<[Term], TermError> = /* How? */
```

`tuple2` should be `.failure` if **any** of `tuple` are `.failure`. Otherwise it is `.success([tuple-elements-in-here])`.

I think I can come up with something that will make this work, but I feel like there ought to be a fairly clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually just trying to recreate the `sequence` function for Haskell Monads in Swift, for the `Result` monad. We can implement it exactly the same way [Haskell implemented it](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html).

```hs
sequence       :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a] 
sequence       =  foldr mcons (return [])
                    where mcons p q = p >>= \x -> q >>= \y -> return (x:y)
```

In Swift, this would look like:

```
func sequence<T, E: Error>(_ arrayOfResults: [Result<T, E>]) -> Result<[T], E> {
    return arrayOfResults.reduce(.success([])) { (p, q) in
        return p.flatMap { x in return q.map { y in return x + [y] } }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let tuple2 = sequence(tuple)
```

Comment: Boom! That's about what I was after. Thanks! … Can the inner bit change to… `return p.flatMap { p in return q.map { q in p + [q] } }`? It builds … I'm not sure it's correct!

Comment: @Benjohn Ah, you're right. There is no `map` in Haskell so they had to use `flatMap` (`>>=`), but you could use `map` in Swift, but I don't recommend using the same names `p` and `q` though. It's confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can define an `extension` on `Array` that converts an `Array<Result<Value,Error>> to`Result,Error>` like below.

```
extension Array {
    func flatMapResult<Value, Error>() -> Result<Array<Value>,Error> where Element == Result<Value,Error> {
        let valuesAndErrors = self.map { element -> (value: Value?, error: Error?) in
            switch element {
            case .failure(let error):
                return (nil, error)
            case .success(let value):
                return (value, nil)
            }
        }
        if let firstElementWithError = valuesAndErrors.first(where: {$0.error != nil}), let firstError = firstElementWithError.error {
            return .failure(firstError)
        } else {
            let values = valuesAndErrors.compactMap { $0.value }
            return .success(values)
        }
    }
}
```

Code sample for usage:

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case err
}

let arrayOfResults: Array<Result<Int,MyError>> = [.success(8), .success(2), .success(3)] // success([8, 2, 3])
let arrayOfResultsWithFailure = arrayOfResults + [.failure(.err)] // failure(__lldb_expr_2.MyError.err)

arrayOfResults.flatMapResult()
arrayOfResultsWithFailure.flatMapResult()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function and throw error in case of failure.

Something like this:

```
let tuple2: Result<Array<Term>, TermError>

do {
    let result = try tuple.map { result -> Term in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            throw error
        case .success(let value):
            return value
        }
    }

    tuple2 = .success(result)
} catch let error as TermError {
    tuple2 = .failure(error)
} catch { fatalError("Unknown error") }

print(tuple2)
```

You can move this into extension to reuse.